# Failure to Add Layer from a WMS Provider QGIS 2.14

Tags: qgis, wms

I just installed QGIS 2.14 using the osgeo4w-setup-x86_64.exe When I tried to add a layer from a WMS/WMTS provider, it failed citing Bad Request as the reason. I was using Lizardtech server but the result was the same with DM Solution as the server. Exact message:

> Failed to download capabilities: Download of capabilities failed:
>   Error downloading
>   http://wms.lizardtech.com/lizardtech/iserv/ows?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
>   - server replied: Bad Request

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The Adress is wrong, or the server not working... You get the same message when you put it into your browser but you should get the Capabilities document. Also the plain server is not responding if you open the link with the adress http://wms.lizardtech.com/lizardtech/iserv/ows? . There should be an answer there already, what means that something is broken.

You may try with another wms. Following is an example for a Openstreetmap WMS. Try if this one works. Then everything with QGis is ok.

http://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Comment: @michaeltan if this has worked for you please mark it as the answer.